# wherePivot laravel method and "in" operator

Tags: php, laravel

I have two `Course` and `User` models that there is a ManyToMany relationship between them.

And have a pivot table named `course_user` that has extra columns like this:

```
course_id
user_id
status
score
```

`status` column hold an integer value that shows register status of User in a Course.

And Now I want to fetch all courses of a specific User that have a specific `course_id` and it's status has Included At least one of an array values.

For that I wrote this :

```
$user->courses()
    ->where('course_user.course_id', $course->course_id)
    ->wherePivot('status', 'not in', [1, 3, 10])
    ->count()
```

But that does not work and does not return what I expect .

Even I try to see generated sql from above code that shown **[wherePivot](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L93)** method does not work properly and ignores `not in` sql operator. that return below sql :

```
"select * from `courses` inner join `course_user` on `courses`.`course_id` = `course_user`.`course_id` where `course_user`.`user_id` = ? and `course_user`.`course_id` = ? and `course_user`.`status` != ? and `courses`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

what is Problem and how can I solve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `whereNotIn` method

Something like that:

```
$user->courses()
    ->where('course_user.course_id', $course->course_id)
    ->whereNotIn('status', [1, 3, 10])
    ->count()
```

Answer (score 1):

**make a relationship in User Model**

> public function courses(){return $this->hasMany('Course', 'user_id');}

**make a relationship in CourseUser Model**

> public function users() {return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');}

**now call this relation in this way**

{{$user->courses()->whereNotIn('status',[1,3,10])->get()}}

Hope it works :)